# Fetch rows of only for transaction code LOBA

Tags: sql, db2, subquery, window-functions

Input table:

```
agent_id  transaction_code date       state_code
12345233      LARA         20230509      FL
12345233      LOBA         20230509      FL
45678342      LARA         20230509      AL
45678342      LOBA         20230509      AL
45678342      LOBA         20230509      AL
68939393      LOBA         20230509      AL
74953738      LOBA         20230509      GA
68939393      LARA         20230509      FL
68939393      LOBA         20230509      FL
68939393      LOBA         20230509      FL
```

Expected OUTPUT TABLE:

```
agent_id  transaction_code date       state_code
68939393      LOBA         20230509     AL
74953738      LOBA         20230509     GA
```

Current output table:

```
agent_id  transaction_code date       state_code
12345233      LOBA         20230509      FL
45678342      LOBA         20230509      AL
45678342      LOBA         20230509      AL
68939393      LOBA         20230509      AL
74953738      LOBA         20230509      GA
68939393      LOBA         20230509      FL
68939393      LOBA         20230509      FL
```

I want only two rows from the input table which have only the LOBA transaction code for that agent id and not the LARA transaction code, but with the query I am getting all the LOBA transaction.

```
SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTR(A.RECORD_KEY,1,10) AS "PRODUCER_TAX_ID",
CASE WHEN B.SEX_CODE = 'E'THEN TRIM(B.CORPORATE_NAME) ELSE TRIM(B.FIRST_NAME) || TRIM(B.MIDDLE_NAME) || TRIM(B.LAST_NAME) END AS "PRODUCER_NAME",
SUBSTR(A.RECORD_KEY,11,2) AS "STATE_CODE", SUBSTR(A.RECORD_AREA,29,8) AS "APPOINTMENT_EFFECTIVE_DATE", A.ORIGINATOR_CD AS "USER_ID",
DECODE(A.FILE_MAINT_TRX_CD ,'LOBA','ADD') AS "TRANSACTION_TYPE",
SUBSTR(A.RECORD_AREA,134,1) AS "SEND_TO_STATE", A.LOG_DT_R AS "LAST_CHANGED_DT" , A.LOG_TIME AS "TIME_PROCESSED" 
FROM PPL_S01.REG_HIST A , PPL_S01.MPR B
WHERE SUBSTR(A.RECORD_KEY,1,10) NOT IN (select DISTINCT SUBSTR(A.RECORD_KEY,1,10)
from PPL_S01.REG_HIST R
where A.FILE_MAINT_TRX_CD = 'LARA' AND SUBSTR(R.RECORD_KEY,1,10) = SUBSTR(A.RECORD_KEY,1,10))
AND A.FILE_MAINT_TRX_CD = 'LOBA' 
AND B.MSTR_AGENT_ID = SUBSTR(A.RECORD_KEY,1,10)
```

Comment: please don't ask the same question multiple times, edit your original question and add the additional information.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are trying to get the LOBA records where there isn't a LARA code record for the same agent? If this is the case then the following should work:

```
SELECT IT1.*
FROM INPUT_TABLE IT1
WHERE IT1.TRANSACTION_CODE = 'LOBA'
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT IT2.TRANSACTION_CODE
                FROM INPUT_TABLE IT2
                WHERE IT1.AGENT_ID = IT2.AGENT_ID
                AND IT2.TRANSACTION_CODE = 'LARA')
;
```

Comment: the query  I am using has the same logic but I am getting all the records even if there are 2 LOBA records for the same agent....please look at the query that I mentioned that I am using

Comment: When I run my query against your data I get the same result as your Expected Output Data (i.e. 2 records) - so I'm not sure what else you are expecting?

Comment: I made some changes in input data please check once....basically even if the agent id  have LARA but the state code is different I only want whose agent id have for a particular state code

Comment: Then just add "AND IT1.STATE_CODE = IT2.STATE_CODE" to the WHERE clause of the sub-select. If this still doesn't give you want you want then you probably need to pause and think more clearly about what you are trying to do. Then update your question with clear logic rules that need to be applied, sample data that covers all your use cases and the result you want to achieve. For you to provide additional information, such as adding a new state_code column to your data, after someone has has given you an answer is just wasting everyone's time

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want rows of agents that only had LOBA transactions. If so, you can use window functions to flag agents that do not fulfull the requirement, then filter them out:

```
select *
from (
    select r.*,
        max(case when transaction_code <> 'LOBA' then 1 else 0 end) 
            over(partition by agent_id) flag
    from reg_hist r
) r
where flag = 0
```

Conversely, if were are looking for rows of agents that had no LARA transaction, you would change the conditional expression to:

```
case when transaction_code = 'LARA' then 1 else 0 end
```

As opposed to solutions using subqueries or joins, the upshot of the window functions approach is that the query scans the table only once - so it is often more efficient.

PS: your current query does not seem related to your data whatsoever.

Comment: with your flag approach can you tell me if we have same agent id have LARA exists but for different state code how to check that.....I added some field in input data can you check

Comment: @ZEHRA: probably you want `partition by agent_id, state)`. Note that it is not a good practice on Stack Overflow to substantially modify your question after answers are posted.